# Problem with laptop internal keyboard and mouse

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, acer, 20.10

For a month I've  got a problem with my Acer TravelMate-P645-SG laptop's internal keyboard and touchpad that are not recognized. Now I'm using a USB keyboard, but it's quite annoying.

It all started on Ubuntu 20.04, after some updates (maybe caused by a kernel update). I've done a lot of tests, upgrading, downgrading, etc. Now I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 20.10 and the kernel to the latest available version (5.10.8-051008-generic), but still no solution can be found.

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. ES603 Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1570 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. HUAWEI Mobile Broadband Module
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b495 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub</code>
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 48)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: It must be a hardware issue.

Comment: I've found the solution. The problem was the BIOS that need to be updated to work with new kernels. The big problem is that Acer BIOS can be updated only from Windows....